# Can I tell spark.read.json that my files are gzipped?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an s3 bucket with nearly 100k gzipped JSON files.

These files are called `[timestamp].json` instead of the more sensible `[timestamp].json.gz`.

I have other processes that use them so renaming is not an option and copying them is even less ideal.

I am using `spark.read.json([pattern])` to read these files. If I rename the filename to contain the `.gz` this works fine, but whilst the extension is just `.json` they cannot be read.

Is there any way I can tell spark that these files are gzipped?

Answer (score 17):

SparkSession can read compressed json file directly, just like this:

`val json=spark.read.json("/user/the_file_path/the_json_file.log.gz")
json.printSchema()`

Comment: Yes, I know, but it seems to infer compression from the file name. files ending with just `json` or `.json.gzip` seem to fail when using `spark.read.json(FILENAME)`

Comment: @Hans did you manage to find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 1):

In case that you need to read json.gz files from s3, this is an example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("SparkExample") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark_context = spark.sparkContext
spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", <aws_key>)
spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", <aws_secret>)
spark_context._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")


df = spark.read.format('json').load('s3a://bucket/part-00045-7dfe93dd-576a-414b-b167-deaaf1d655f2.c000.json.gz')
df.show()
```