# Is it possible to untar a tar.gz file on HDFS and put it in different HDFS folder without bringing it to local systems

Tags: apache-spark, unix, hadoop, hdfs

I have employee_mumbai.tar.gz file inside this I have name.json and salary.json.
And the tar.gz is present in HDFS location. Is it possible to untar/Unzip the gzip file and put the json files in HFDS folder without bringing it to a local file system.
N.B:
Please remember it is not a text file and both json file unique information.

Please let me know if it can be achieved to read the both file separately in different data frame directly too in spark.

Comment: Last I checked, Spark should be able to read json within a targz file

Comment: This will work if it is a text file and if only one file in GZ compression
But in my case inside Tar.gz ✓I have 
a.json
b.json.
I achieved it by Java

Comment: No. Spark can read all files within an archive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I tell spark.read.json that my files are gzipped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253022/can-i-tell-spark-read-json-that-my-files-are-gzipped)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /data/<data.gz> | gzip -d | hdfs dfs -put - /data/
```

Comment: This still downloads the whole file locally

Comment: That is why we can not use and more over it works for Text file or JSON file only if GZ file contain only one JSON file like a.json But in this case tar.gz contains 2 different json file. A.json and B.json